# matlab heatmap plot changing axis directions

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, heatmap, contour

I have a function `f(v,z)` and `z = [0:0.01:1]`, `v = [1:0.01:5]`. 
I first create a cell, denoted by C, to record the coordinates of this `(v,z),` and from this `C`, I fill in a matrix of the value of `f(v,z)`. So my cell `C` look like the following

```
C = (0,5),   (0.01,5),   (0.02,5),....., (1,5)
    (0,4.99),(0.01,4.99),(0.02,4.99),...,(1,4.99)
    ...
    (0,1),   (0.01,1),   (0.02,1),......,(1,1)
```

So when viewing cell C as the coordinates in the 2D space, the vertical axis (the column) is `z` and the horizontal axis (the row) is `v`. And the value `f(v,z)` is built up on these coordinates. So one can imagining plotting a 3D picture.

Then I fill matrix `M`, which contains the value of `f(v,z)` according to the cell `C`. Then I want to do the heat map (or contour would also be fine), but when I use `colormap` or `contour`, it seems that matlab just does not plot the figure according to my specific direction of v and z as specified by my cell `C`. Also, the range of the two axes does not look right. I wonder if there is good way to control the plotting directions of the axes?

Comment: `set(gca,'YDir','normal');`

Comment: @BrendanFrick I did `contour(M),set(gca,'YDir','normal');` it does not help...For example, I am expecting to see a curve representing the value of `f(v,z)=0`. I looked at the matrix `M`, this curve appears in the bottom part of matrix `M`. However, when I looked at the contour figure I just plot, the curve appears on the top of the picture, and the shape is upside down...

Comment: `contour()` by default plots in the `normal` direction, so you'll actually want to do `set(gca,'YDir','reverse')`. This will have 1,2,.. from top to bottom

Comment: @BrendanFrick thanks! I just tried it. It works. I wonder if there are something more generic way of generating such contour or heatmap based on the given coordinates. Because I eventually want to first plot a relation between `v` and `z`, e.g., `plot(z,v=g(z))`, sth. like that, then on top of this graph, I plot the heatmap `f(v,z)`. The idea is that I want to project `f(v,z)` in 2D and in that 2D space, I also need to partition the space by several functions `v=g(z)`

Comment: You can. Most of the image functions (`imagesc`, `countour`,`colormap`,`pcolor`, etc.) will plot in matrix space. On the otherhand `surf()` requires you set the unit space. You can set your grid with `[X,Y] = meshgrid(x_vec,y_vec)`, and then `surf(X,Y,ones(size(X)));`  `view(0,90)`;